# ExecuteScalar() not returning full contents of cell

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure which returns an XML string. When I copy this directly from the table, I get everything exactly as I expect it.

However, when I try to run this stored procedure with C#, the ExecuteScalar() returns only 46 lines of the 70 lines I'm expecting.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=BMRSK;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand buildXML = new SqlCommand("usp_BUILD_RISKCALC_XML", con))
    {
        buildXML.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        con.Open();

        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml((string)buildXML.ExecuteScalar());
        xdoc.Save("Test.xml");
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get from the line

```
xdoc.LoadXml((string)buildXML.ExecuteScalar());
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The
>   following elements are not closed: ARGUMENT, ARGUMENT-LIST, OPERATION,
>   OPERATION-LIST, RISKCALC. Line 1, position 2034.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code of the stored procedure?

Comment: The opening xml tags and closing xml tags are not matched.  There is an error in the xml.  Post XML.

Comment: I have confirmed by right clicking and copying the cell contents after running the stored procedure that it works. Now, I'm trying to automate it, but ExecuteScalar() is only returning the first 46 lines. There should be 70.

Comment: Here is the stored procedure: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9fbf482d4fbcaa1d4a36

Comment: How many *characters* are being returned? Does it match up with [this](https://support2.microsoft.com/?ID=KB;EN-US;Q310378)? Any reason for not using [`ExecuteXmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: Yes! The ExecuteScalar only returns 2033 characters.

And it's my first time doing something like this, should probably read the documentation a little better. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteScalar only reads 2033 characters. Use ExecuteXmlReader instead.

```
 private static void BuildXML()
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=BMRSK;Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         using (SqlCommand buildXML = new SqlCommand("usp_BUILD_RISKCALC_XML", con))
         {
              buildXML.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

              con.Open();

              XmlReader xmlReader = buildXML.ExecuteXmlReader();
              XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
              xdoc.Load(xmlReader);
              xdoc.Save("Test.xml");
         }
     }
}
```